# SQL query to update multiple tables with same column name

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database that include many tables with have same column name and I would like to run a SQLITE3 query to change the values of all tables.

```
  Table XXX (id integer, name text);
  Table YYY (id integer, .....);
  Table ZZZ (id integer, .....);
  Table....
```

To run a query on all table which jave a field name "id" I used the query:
select name from sqlite_master where sql like ('%id%');

But, how could I use the UPDATE query with the list of tables?

Comment: Can you give a more realistic example? Is this your actual situation?

Comment: I have a database which includes a default key value for all tables. I would like to change all default in all tables in one query. This key is not unique, there is other columns that are unique but all belong to same id.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with regular sql without simply listing all table/column combinations.

Possible solutions could be functions/procedures or other ways to execute dynamically generated sql.

Comment: The list of tables that includes th "I'd" field is appear above. Select name from sqlite_master where.... But I need to include in update a list of tables and not one

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger in order to update as many tables you want after insert in a single table .

example trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_tables
AFTER INSERT ON XXX
BEGIN

INSERT INTO YYY (new.id,new.integer);
INSERT INTO ZZZ (new.id,new.integer);

END
```